# How to test api method for stability and ability to get multiple request simultaneously using scalatest?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka, playframework-2.2

I have an api method that calls some service class method and gets a future of Money object (case class):

```
 // getMoneyFromBank() returns a Future[Money]

  def getMoney(): Action[JsValue] = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[Password] match {
      case JsSuccess(password, _) => getMoneyFromBank(password).map {
        case money: Money => Ok(money)
      } recover {
        case ex =>
          InternalServerError(ex.getMessage)
      }

      case JsError(errors) => Future(BadRequest("Errors! " + errors.mkString))
    }
  }
```

getMoney method going to be called allot and i want to make sure its very stable and can handle number of calls simultaneously, what would be the best way to test that using scalatest? how do I test this kind of scenario very well?

I work with play 2.6 and scalatest 2.2.6 (and scalatestplus-play 1.5.1)

Comment: What you are describing sounds like load testing. You should look at this: http://gatling.io/download/

Comment: gatling would be better but you also can do a work around with scalaCheck